# Not inserting duplicate items into MySQL DB - Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am persisting some data from an API into a MySQL db using Symfony2 and Doctrine.  I have an entity called Gig and I use annotations to set up the constraints. I think the relevant part of this looks like:

```
namespace London\HelloBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Gig
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"Artist", "ConcertDate"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Gig
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Artist", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $artist;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="ConcertDate", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $concertDate;
```

In my controller I use Buzz https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle to go through the API and persist the bits I want to the DB.  This all works fine for the first import.

However I have set the combination of Artist and ConcertDate columns to be unique because I don't want to read the same items from the API into the database twice.  When I trigger the action that handles this however I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Plaid-2014-08-12' for key      'UNIQ_ED7D66426F593B176DAA24E'
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception: PDOException »
```

I think this is as it should be but what I really want is to persist the new data and skip over the data that I already have.  Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:**
Adding the code that persists the data to db as per comment request.

```
namespace London\APIBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use London\HelloBundle\Entity\Gig;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $buzz = $this->container->get('buzz');
    $response = $buzz->get('http://myapiuri');
    echo $buzz->getLastRequest(). "\n";
    $content = $response->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($content);
    $stuff=$data->resultsPage->results->event;
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($stuff) ; $i++) {
        $gig = new Gig();
        if(isset($stuff[$i]->performance[0])){
            $gig->setArtist($stuff[$i]->performance[0]->displayName);
        }
        $gig->setConcertDate($stuff[$i]->start->date);
        $gig->setVenueName($stuff[$i]->venue->displayName);
        $gig->setGenre($stuff[$i]->type);
        $gig->setVenueAddress('45 Queen Caroline Street, London, England W6 9QH');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($gig);
        $em->flush();   

    }
    return $this->render('LondonAPIBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code that persists the entity to the db?

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyTree I have edited the post to show that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an entity with the same key already exists and only insert if it does not.

```
$exists = $em->getRepository('London\HelloBundle\Entity\Gig')->findBy(array(
    'Artist' => $gig->getArtist(), 
    'ConcertDate' => $gig->getConcertDate()
);

if(!$exists) {
    $em->persist($gig);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Alternatively, you could catch the duplicate exception.

```
try {
    $em->persist($gig);
    $em->flush(); 
}
catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

    //if the error is not for duplicates, throw the error
    if($e->getErrorCode() != $error_code_for_dupes) {
        throw $e;
    }

    //otherwise ignore it
}
```

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyTree.  I'm not going to be in a position to try this out for a day or two.  Wanted to say thanks tho and let you know I've not ignored your help :)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because your first solution does solve the problem.  The second option didn't work - first there was an issue with $e->getErrorCode (switching to $e->getCode was ok) but if($e->getCode() != 1062) never seemed to work and allow the inserts to continue. Thanks again tho!

Answer (score -2):

Remove unique constrain,

```
uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"Artist", "ConcertDate"})}
```

if its possible to have 2 concerts same artist in same date.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  I want to keep this constraint (or one like it - maybe also including Venue).  What I'm really looking for is how to get get Doctrine / Symfony to pass over data in the API that is already in db and persist only what isn't already in there.